# Why style is not recognized by td element in razor?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

I have this column in the HTML table in Razor code. I want to change its background on the basis of status value.

```
  <td @(@InspectionReport.Status == 0 ? style = "Background-Color: lightgreen;" : @InspectionReport.Status == 1 ? style = "Background-Color: lightgray;" : @InspectionReport.Status == 2 ? style = "Background-Color: blue;" : @InspectionReport.Status == 3 ? style = "Background-Color: yellow;" : "")>
```

but it says that

> **style** doesn't exist in current context

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than Using **style** directly, use some class in `td` element

```
<td class="@(InspectionReport.Status == 0 ? "lightgreen" : InspectionReport.Status == 1 ? "lightgray" :InspectionReport.Status == 2 ? "blue" : InspectionReport.Status == 3 ? "yellow" : "")"></td>
```

then create classes in your **css** file as follows:

```
td.lightgreen{
    background-color:lightgreen;
}
td.lightgray{
    background-color:lightgreen;
}
td.blue{
    background-color:blue;
}
td.yellow{
    background-color:yellow;
}
```